# Google reviews star on Google Search description from own site's reviews

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets, review

I am a web developer and one of my clients has been approached by a company selling feedback services.

The company is basically selling a review plugin (with respective background services) which can be integrated in the client's web site (original articles written by the client's authors).

The feedback stars are then supposed to appear in the Google Search description.

We also do already have our own review software. However, so far we haven't marked it up with rich snippets yet (for several reasons).

Now my question is, whether our own rating system, once it would be properly marked up and schema-ed, not be shown in the Google description because it's data that doesn't come from an external (trusted?) source like e.g. this company which does provide feedback services?

Answer (score 0):

Any website can include reviews and/or ratings which are marked up with schema.org, and they will show in google's search results. They don't need to be provided by an external company, they can be submitted to the company website by their own customers,  anonymously for example.